# How can i use variables in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

How can i use variables in ansible playbook?

like they can be used in bash scripting and docker

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable in ansible playbook like:

```
- name: Create Directory
  file:
    path: "{{ directory_path }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  become: yes
```

In ansible you put the variable in double curly braces.
in the above example `directory_path` is a variable.
you can read about ansible variables [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_variables.html).